# NameError: name 'unicode' is not define while using latex2pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, unicode

I try to convert .tex file to pdf:

```
from tex import latex2pdf
import pdflatex
import sys


pdf = latex2pdf("str('\\documentclass{article}\r\n\\begin{document}\r\nHello Palo Alto!\r\n\\end{document}\r\n')")
```

I got an error:

```
    File "C:\Users\mvideo\Desktop\python_files\pdf_latex\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    pdf = tex2pdf(u'\documentclass{article}\n\begin{document}\r\nHello Palo Alto!\r\n\end{document}\r\n')
  File "C:\Users\mvideo\Desktop\python_files\pdf_latex\venv\lib\site-packages\tex.py", line 178, in tex2pdf
    return convert(tex_source, 'tex', 'pdf', **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mvideo\Desktop\python_files\pdf_latex\venv\lib\site-packages\tex.py", line 109, in convert
    assert isinstance(tex_source, unicode)
```

NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

How should I solve my problem?

Comment: Please share the full Traceback

Comment: It is done now..

Comment: `unicode` is from Python2, it doesn't exist in Python3.  So you could try running the code with Python2, or see if there's an upgraded version of the package that supports Python3.

Comment: I tried to use str() function